# Using <span> value that is created in an external file

Tags: javascript, html

I have two files: a javascript file called simplecart.js, it creates a value that gets displayed in  `<span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span>` in the other file I have, a html file. The html file contains this code:

```
<span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span>
<span id="quantityText"></span>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity"),
        quantityText = document.getElementById("quantityText");
    if (parseInt(quantity.innerHTML, 10) === 1) {
        quantityText.innerHTML = "article";
    } else {
        quantityText.innerHTML = "articles";
    }
</script>
```

**The problem is:** 
It seems as if the code can't get the value between `<span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span>` (keep in mind that that value is created in the external file simplecart.js) and now alwasy displays 'articles' because it can't see if that value is '1'.

I hope someone can help me with fixing this,
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does `parseInt(quantity.innerHTML, 10)` return when you debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your simplecart.js file looks, it is highly possible that your javascript code in your html file is actually run too early (before the document is actually ready).
You should delay any DOM manipulation, e.g. with (or with jquery):

```
document.onload = function () {
    var quantity = document .......
}
```

It would be better to use a binding library for that (like Angular.js) but you could update the field periodically as a quick solution:

```
var updatePlural = function () {
    var quantity = document .......
}
setInterval(updatePlural, 250); // every 250ms
```

Comment: I think this is the problem, how would I be able to run this code after the rest of the page has loaded? (Or actually, after the included simplecart.js file has loaded the value into the <span> tag?)

Comment: I updated with a suggestion (not very clean though because it does active monitoring).

Answer (score 0):

You need to delay running your JS until *after* the JS that populates the span with data runs.

Since your script element appears immediately after it, it is going to pull the value immediately. There is no better way to ensure that other JS *doesn't* run first.

The specifics of how to delay your JS until the best moment will depend on when the relevant code in simplecart.js runs,